# cutting title character in joomla contant module

Tags: php, joomla

i need your help in this case; i have module in joomla and want to cutting title with specified a limit from joomla library string.php. i change this code :

```
<?php if ($params->get('show_title', 1)) : ?>
            <h3 itemprop="name">
    <?php if ($params->get('link_titles') && $params->get('access-view')) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($displayData->slug, $displayData->catid)); ?>" itemprop="url"><?php echo $this->escape($displayData->title); ?></a>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php echo $this->escape($displayData->title); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </h3>
```

to this code :

```
<?php if ($params->get('show_title', 1)) : ?>
            <h3 itemprop="name">
                <?php if ($params->get('link_titles') && $params->get('access-view')) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($displayData->slug, $displayData->catid)); ?>" itemprop="url">
<?php   
$limit =100; 
if (strlen($this->item->text) > $limit) {
echo (substr($this->item->text, 0, $limit)) . " ... ";
}
else {      
echo  $this->escape($displayData->title); } ?></a><?php else : ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </h3>
```

but not work. 
thanks for your attention guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla has a built-in [JHtmlString/truncate method](https://docs.joomla.org/API16:JHtmlString/truncate) which you can use, I've had good success using it with some of our templates and overrides.

This method would let you simplify your code and you could replace you entire last php block with something like the following

```
<?php   
 $limit =100; 
 echo JHTML::_('string.truncate', ($this->item->text), $limit, false, false);
?>
```

More about JHtmlString/truncate: https://docs.joomla.org/API16:JHtmlString/truncate

Some example code which might be helpful:
https://gist.github.com/2dpi/a540527a64f9f0093392

https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/JHtmlString/truncateComplex/php-jhtmlstring-truncatecomplex-method-examples.html

Good luck!